# Simpy: Add process during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, simpy

Is there a way to add a SimPy process to a SimPy environment when the latter is already running? The context is as follows:

I have successfully implemented a queueing network for a traffic system using SimPy, where cars are propagated across links. The origin and destination of each car is known at "compile" time, as is their departure time. The simulation thus describes how they are moved across the network, where the propagation speed depends on the prevailing densities. If there is a lot of cars on a link, their speed decreases, as in reality. If there are too many cars on a link, they are retained from entering until another car has left, etc.

My question now would be, can I also supply the traffic demand during run time? Imagine there's an overarching process that generates cars in real-time, when my SimPy simulation is already running. How could I do this? Is there any tutorial or example available?

Any help or comment is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We invested a lot of time and effort in documentation.  Please feel free to read it:

https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/events.html#processes-are-events-too
https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/process_interaction.html
https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/index.html

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks a lot for the reply. I've read the tutorial several times, including the examples. As I wrote, I have a fully functional code, in which all cars are added to the environment by using env.process(), before invoking env.run(). My question above is, what happens in the case where a process simply does not exist yet at the time when env.run() is invoked? Can I add a process later (for instance when a car is created by an external simulator), and will it be considered in the remainder of the simulation? I have not seen any such example. Thanks again for your further comments.

Comment: I don't know if you saw my comment as I forgot to tag you. If you have any further comment on this, please let me know. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You can start new processes with env.process() at any time, no matter if env.run() is currently being invoked or not.

Comment: You have to be careful when adding "externally" triggered events/processes in Simpy. If its execution time is before the next event the Environment is waiting on the timing will not work properly.